# Set & animate Date time in a Label

Tags: swift, date, timer, uilabel

I'm having hard time accomplishing something. I'm using `Firebase` as database. When a user creates a new poll post, they also have to set an expiration date. In the app itself, I have to display the expiration date as a timer (or countdown?) in a `UILabel`, showing how much time that's left before the voting should be disabled.

Here's what I have so far:

```
extension Date {


func offsetFromNow() -> String {
       let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
       formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
       formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
       return formatter.string(from: Date(), to: self)!
   }
}

class PostPollCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var seconds = 60 
    var timer = Timer()
    var isTimerRunning = false
    func updateView() {
        if let expirationTimeInt = post?.pollExpirationTime {
            let expirationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(expirationTimeInt))
            self.pollExpirationDate.text = "poll ends in: " + expirationDate.offsetFromNow()
        }
    }

   func runTimer() {
   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        seconds -= 1     //This will decrement(count down)the days, hours, min and seconds.
      // pollExpirationDate.text = Update the label with the total time left
    }
}
```

The only thing the code above does is to simply get the date and set's the `pollExpirationDate.text` to basically whatever time it is. The output format is like this:

> 3d 3h 34min 5s

**What I have to do and don't know how (need help with the code):**

1. I have to make sure that the time is not negative. Right now, it simply displays the time, even if it's negative. If the time is negative, it means the **pollExpirationDate** `UILabel` should simply say that the poll has ended, disable the voting options (which are `UIButton`) and show a block with the result (now, I don't expect this from you, this is not even set yet at this point, I just need to know where should I run this code, that's all)
2. I'm downloading the date from `FirebaseDatabase` and setting the `UILabel`, but I don't know how to create the timer (or countdown) that should animate the `pollExpirationDate` `UILabel` (time left)
3. When the countdown reaches 0 seconds, the voting should be disabled (the time has expired)

I've never done any of this, so help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two variable globally in class to check status of timer is working or paused/stopped.

```
fileprivate var timeWorking                     : Bool = false
var timer                                       : Timer?
```

Then, created one method to get every date component same as like you have described.

```
func timeLeftExtended(date:Date) -> NSAttributedString {

    let cal = Calendar.current
    let now = Date()
    let calendarUnits : NSCalendar.Unit = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
    let components = (cal as NSCalendar).components(calendarUnits, from: now, to: date, options: [])

    let fullCountDownStr = ""

    if(components.day!.description == "0" || components.day!.description == "00") {

        // This will display hour, minute, and second
        fullCountDownStr = "\(components.hour!.description)h " + "\(components.minute!.description)m " + "\(components.second!.description)s "

    } else if (components.day!.description == "0" || components.day!.description == "00") && (components.hour!.description == "0" || components.hour!.description == "00") {

        // This will display minute and second
        fullCountDownStr = "\(components.minute!.description)m " + "\(components.second!.description)s "

    } else if (components.day!.description == "0" || components.day!.description == "00") && (components.hour!.description == "0" || components.hour!.description == "00") && (components.minute!.description == "0" || components.minute!.description == "00") {

        // This will display second only
        fullCountDownStr = "\(components.second!.description)s "

    } else {

        // This will display day, hour, minute, second
        fullCountDownStr = "\(components.day!.description)d " + "\(components.hour!.description)h " + "\(components.minute!.description)m " + "\(components.second!.description)s "

    }

    let mutableStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullCountDownStr, attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])

    for (index,char) in mutableStr.string.enumerated() {
        if(char == "d" || char == "h" || char == "m" || char == "s") {
            mutableStr.removeAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
            mutableStr.addAttributes([.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
            mutableStr.addAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)], range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
        }
    }

    return mutableStr
}
```

This will give me date in `3d 3h 34min 5s` format.

To animate counter of make Timer and call this method.

```
func setupTimer() {

    if let expirationTimeInt = post?.pollExpirationTime {
        let expirationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(expirationTimeInt))

        if expirationDate == Date() {
            self.pollExpirationDate.text = "expirationDate is Today's date"
        } else if date! > Date() {
            if(!timeWorking) {
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateCountDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                self.timeWorking = true
            }
        } else if date! < Date() {
             self.pollExpirationDate.text = "expirationDate is gone"
        }
    }
}
```

Update counter method will count down your date timer.

```
@objc func updateCountDown() {
    if let expirationTimeInt = post?.pollExpirationTime {
        let expirationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(expirationTimeInt))

        self.pollExpirationDate.attributedText = self.timeLeftExtended(date: expirationDate)
    }
}
```

Call setup timer method from viewDidLoad. This is working code for me, I hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, this indeed works, except that when the time is negative, it keeps showing it as negative. How can we fix that? Just one question - say the days and the hours are actually `0` (meaning there are only minutes and seconds left), how can we hide those zeros and just show the remaining time?

Comment: I mean that (negative time) only happens if the app isn't refreshed or in my case, the app isn't recompiled.

Comment: @Dani, For minute and second, you can put condition and returns only required date component from `timeLeftExtended ` method. Please see my updated code.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dani, Happy to help you.